# admob only sends test ad not real ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I followed instructions on https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

I changed the test code in strings.xml to real code. But the app is still showing test ads.(I have not posted the app on play store)

It appears in emulator like this
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6InEecSXedCNmM4eUVrTzVGaFU/view?usp=sharing
Here is activity_main.xml code

```
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/adView" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

and here is a part of java code

```
    Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Mobile Ads SDK will only display test ads on the emulator.  If you switch to debugging on a real device, you will see live, production ads unless you register the device with the addTestDevice call.

As Abishek points out, it is a violation of AdMob policy to request real ads when you're testing and debugging, and this can result in the suspension of your account. The SDK automatically requests test ads to prevent this from happening.

Comment: It is a violation of admob policy to *click* such adds, not to request them in the first place.

Comment: We stress the importance of avoiding false clickthroughs because it's the larger problem, but it is also against policy to cause false impressions by not using test ads.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the live ads during development as it is against AdMob policy to use live ads during development, and doing so could cause the suspension of your AdMob account.

Comment: Does this include house ads as well!! Technically they should allow testing house ads!

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the banner ad unit id. because its the test id, that shows the test ad. You can find them in the `strings.xml`

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
```

Comment: how to change test id to live id