# How To Add Dynamic Ad To AdView In Admob Android?

Tags: android, admob

This is My Code:

```
AdView mAdView;
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9233630887794553~4351962429");
// Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
// values/strings.xml.
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Changes every x seconds?

Comment: no, AdView Not Display Real Ad. Display Only Test Add.

Comment: That's not a problem. You'll get test ads on emulator/developer device.

Comment: I get Test Add In Emulator And Also in Real Test Device But Only Show Test Google Adds Not real Adds?? Is There Any Registration for Real Adds ??

Answer (score 0):

Check the 2 answers from this link: [admob only sends test ad not real ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489287/admob-only-sends-test-ad-not-real-ads)

Publish your app and live ads will automatically come.

Comment: Thank you So Much